# Access 2010 Report Calculation using an ammount that is calculated in a form

Tags: ms-access, report

I have the tables Members, Contribution, Payments and Household.
I have a  payment Form where I calculate a discount for people when they have more than one family member on the club. I need that calculated number in my report next to some information as First_Name, Last_name, Account_number which are located in my tables but not that calculated number. I need to know how i get the number which I calculate in my payment form in  my report.

I am not English I hope you will understand.

Thanks in advance,

Jack

Answer (score 0):

If you have the form open, you can refer to the form in your report:

```
 =MyForm!txtDiscount
```

In later version of MS Access, you can have OpenArgs. Let us say you open the report from a form:

```
 DoCmd.OpenReport "MyReport", acViewPreview, , , , Me.txtDiscount
```

You can then refer to Me.OpenArgs on the report.